# How to format usb drive which is not mounting on Ubuntu and windows? It also shows no partition

Tags: partitioning, usb

In windows as soon as I connect my USB drive, option to format it comes on the screen. In Ubuntu it is not mounting.
I am trying to format my USB drive but in Windows and Ubuntu it won't complete.
I run the `lsblk` command and it shows zero partitions in the USB disk.

[image: This is the screnshot of my terminal]

Recovering the data is not my priority.

Please HELP...

Comment: Next time just copy & paste the text from your lsblk output (terminal window) and use the "code" formatting here, much better than an image of text

Comment: The following link might help you, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `gparted`? Check if it detects the disk.

If it detects the disk, it should show some partitions or unallocated space. To completely reformat the disk-

1. Delete all existing partitions(if any).
2. Create a new partition table from Devices->Create Partition Table.
3. You can choose msdos (MBR) for this case, but GPT is required for >2TB sized disks.
4. Right click on the unallocated space and click New, to create a new partition.
5. Select the format, `ntfs` or `fat32` if you want to use it on windows as well. Done

Comment: I used gparted and it dtects the usb drive but i dont know how to use it.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu

Comment: As its not showing any partition creating a new partition will work?

Comment: Go to Device->Create Partition Table to create a partition table. Then you should right click the unallocated space and click New, and create new partition of required size.

Comment: You can also find videos on gparted usage.

Comment: looks like `lsblk` can see it, sdc with 15G, no partitions yet. Sometimes usb drives are unpartitioned, with a filesystem directly on them, but I'd imagine gparted or disks, or most file managers, would detect that. I thought there'd be an existing question about this, but didn't see one from a quick search, so might as well edit some details into your answer & it'll be "good enough" for a +1

Comment: Legolas thank you for your help. While i was using gparted and creating new partition, first i told to create partition table to create partition. But as  i started doing so he application froze and said i/o error. After that operation is terminated. the first sector of usb is zero(0). Any other way or method?

Comment: I guess it's a hardware issue then. Try running "sudo parted -l" check for errors.